# Header is misaligned with the body of the DataTable

Tags: datatables

Header is misaligned with the body of the DataTable.

Here is the script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     initChartData();
     var table = $('#expenses').DataTable({
         scrollY: 400,
         scrollX: true,
         paging: false,
         fixedColumns: true,
         fixedColumns: {
             left: 1,
         },
         order: [[0, 'desc']],
     });
 });
```

[image]

Comment: There is not enough information in the question for anyone to be able to (easily) recreate your issue. Take a look at [mre] - can you provide one? Also, questions which sound very similar to this have been asked many times before on Stack Overflow. Can you show us what you have researched, so we don't have to suggest things which you have already tried?

Comment: For more general help, you can take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.